# why android studio required to Add non null Asserted(!!) call even after safety is added in Kotlin

Tags: android, null, kotlin, non-nullable

[image]

`it` denote List of Object in the Image.
here checking list is not empty. but showing an error to add (`?`) safety .
but again show an error to add non null Asserted(`!!`) even add safety.
error can fix only after add this.

```
 if (it?.isNotEmpty()!!) {
    //do your work here
 }
```

why android studio required to Add non null Asserted (`!!`) call .

Comment: it is working or not.

Comment: working,,,, but i need to know why android studio required to add non null even safety is added.

Comment: @MuhammedHaris Safe approach.

Comment: "if" only takes true or false, so your expression inside if statement can be null but it should be strictly true or false hence the assertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `it` is nullable (hence the `?` after it). So the statement becomes, in plain English, "if `it` is not null, is it not empty?", which is a Boolean. However, what if `it` is null?

Your evaluation of `it?.isNotEmpty()` produces a `Boolean?`, which is not accepted in an if.

So one possible solution is to say "I know it won't be null at that time" and so replace with `it!!.isNotEmpty()`.

Another option is to break down your if statement furthermore, like such :

```
if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty())
```

Comment: ok,,,but in my question (it?.isNotEmpty()!!).here added both ? and !!,,why android studio required to add both .

Comment: Because the first part, it?.isNotEmpty(), produces Boolean or null (Boolean?). To make it Boolean, you add !!.

Comment: @MuhammedHaris the [style guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) suggests using `if(it?.isNotEmpty() == true)`

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this

```
if (it?.isNotEmpty()==true) {
    //do your work here
}
```